# Why does this regex work in grep but not sed?

Tags: regex, sed, grep

I have two regular expressions:

1. `$ grep -E '\-\- .*$' *.sql`
2. `$ sed -E '\-\- .*$' *.sql`

(I am trying to grep lines in sql files that have comments and remove lines in sql files that have comments)

The grep command works using this regex; however, the sed returns the following error:

`sed: -e expression #1, char 7: unterminated address regex`

What am I doing incorrectly with sed?

(The space after the two hyphens is required for sql comments if you are unfamiliar with MySql comments of this type)

Comment: A rough equivalent of `grep regex` is `sed -n /regex/p` or `sed /regex/!d`. The syntax of your `sed` command is not valid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to use:

```sh
sed -E '\-\- .*$' *.sql
```

Here `sed` command is not correct because you're not really telling `sed` to do something.

It should be:

```sh
sed -n '/-- /p' *.sql
```

and equivalent `grep` would be:

```sh
grep -- '-- ' *.sql
```

or even better with a fixed string search:

```sh
grep -F -- '-- ' *.sql
```

Using `--` to separate pattern and arguments in `grep` command.

There is no need to escape `-` in a regex if it is outside bracket expression (or character class) i.e. `[...]`.

---

Based on comments below it seems OP's intent is to remove commented section in all `*.sql` files that start with 2 hyphens.

You may use this `sed` for that:

```sh
sed -i 's/-- .*//g' *.sql
```

Comment: As stated in the question I am trying to remove the comment from the sql files. So don't I need to select from the start of the comment to the end of the line ($)? Or it will just remove the two hyphens

Comment: In that case use `sed  's/-- .*//' file.sql`

Comment: Ended up using `$ sed -i 's/-- .*//g' *.sql` to get it done, thanks for the help with the regex inside.

Comment: @Daniel Re. the "as stated in the question"; you could have made it much clearer that you're not expecting the sed to do the same thing as the grep; your title says "grep works, sed doesn't". The fact that four people (3 answers, 1 comment)  independently thought the same thing and answered in a very similar manner seems to make this fairly obvious ...

Comment: @tink Yeah, looking back that seemed a little passive aggressive, but I didn't mean for it to sound like that. I was just trying to reference the question in my comment and it came out poorly. I agree the question could have been more clear.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is not the regex, the problem is that `sed` requires a command.  The equivalent of your `grep` would be:

```
 sed -n  '/\-\- .*$/p'
```

You suppress output for non-matching lines `-n` ... you **search** (wrap your regex in slashes) and you **print** `p` (after the last slash).

P.S.: As Anub pointed out, escaping the hyphens `-` inside the regex is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use *sed*'s `\cregexpc` syntax where with `\-<...>` you are telling sed the delimiter `c`haracter you want use is a dash `-`, but you didn't terminate it where it should be: `\-<...>-` also add `d` command to delete those lines.

```
sed '\-\-\-.*$-d' infile
```

see `man sed` about that:

> **\c***regexp***c**
> Match lines matching the regular expression *regexp*. The **c** may be any character.

if default `/` was used this was not required so:

```
sed '/--.*$/d' infile
```

or simply:

```
sed '/^--/d' infile
```

and more accurately:

```
sed '/^[[:blank:]]*--/d' infile
```